# windows server 2008 or windows WEBserver 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a question regarding what version of windows webserver would be best in my situation.

The requirements are:

host one or more C# ASP.NET MVC web apps under one or more domains
install and use mysql 5 as database
run php5 web applications

thats about it. It wont be a heavy load website, no clustering etc.

So what would you recommend: windows server 2008 standard or windows webserver 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7 is the optimal solution since it would allow for PHP, handle those nice ASP.NET MVC custom URLs without additional tools like a URL Rewriter.  Since you are using MySQL for your website you'll have no issue getting the lower cost edition of Windows 2008 as well.  Also, PHP is no performance issue on IIS any longer.

```
http://php.iis.net/
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/licensing-web-server.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Webserver is basically just a cheaper licenced version with some of the general domain/networking features disabled.  If you are building a webserver then it is usually a good choice.

Compare the features here...
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx

Comment: So installing php & mysql wont be a problem? Btw. would you suggest using an additional hardware firewall with the wiindows server (app wont be a high security website)?

Comment: Yes, you need an additional firewall of some sort.  Although windows has got a lot more secure in recent versions I would still not leave it public facing.

Comment: Basically for your webserver you should use web edition unless you want to utilize other *Windows* roles with the box. (i.e.: DNS, DHCP etc). You can install any other programs on the box you want, just not other windows roles and services. Do note that for licensing they expect the website public facing and not internal only.